# How can I import Excel file columns in Python and do multiple linear regression between columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, function

I have a lot of columns of numbers (for example, dependent, independent1, independent2, independent3, independent4 and independent5) in Excel file. I needed to import these columns into Python and find linear regression between Dependent variable and 5 independent variables.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel('Nguyen1.xlsx')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use library xlrd
pip install xlrd

```
    import xlrd
    loc = ("path of file") 

    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc) 
    sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0) 

    sheet.cell_value(0, 0) 

    print(sheet.row_values(1))
```

Comment: Hi @Anchal Gupta, thanks but your code is not doing anything to find out multiple linear regression between columns in Excel.